# How to use ua-parser-js in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, user-agent, ua-parser

I want os name, os version, browser name, browser version and device from the user agent. How can I use user agent parser js in my application in angular 4. I tried ng2-device-detector@1.0.0 but it doent return me the os version and device. Please help me

Answer (score 5):

To add it to *package.json*:

```
npm install ua-parser-js
```

To use it in your components or services **you need an import for it to work**:

```
import { UAParser } from 'ua-parser-js'; 

let parser = new UAParser();
console.log(parser.getResult());
```

I found the missing import in this other SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171046/5873570).
Then you can use the [documentation](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js) to get whatever information you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The UAParser.js [documentation](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js) is your best ally.

You can get OS name and version, browser name and other information using UAParser.js like that:

```
var parser = new UAParser();
// by default it takes ua string from current browser's window.navigator.userAgent
console.log(parser.getResult());
var result = parser.getResult();

console.log(result.browser);        // {name: "Chromium", version: "15.0.874.106"}
console.log(result.device);         // {model: undefined, type: undefined, vendor: undefined}
console.log(result.os);             // {name: "Ubuntu", version: "11.10"}
console.log(result.os.version);     // "11.10"
console.log(result.engine.name);    // "WebKit"
console.log(result.cpu.architecture);   // "amd64"
```