# Why can I use import statements in libraries that only support CommonJS modules?

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules, commonjs, ua-parser

[Ua-parser-js](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js) [only supports](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/issues/441) the CommonJS module. And when exporting, the export statement is [not found](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/blob/master/src/ua-parser.js#L835):

```js
    if (typeof(exports) !== UNDEF_TYPE) {
        // nodejs env
        if (typeof module !== UNDEF_TYPE && module.exports) {
            exports = module.exports = UAParser;
        }
        exports.UAParser = UAParser;
    } else {
        // requirejs env (optional)
        if (typeof(define) === FUNC_TYPE && define.amd) {
            define(function () {
                return UAParser;
            });
        } else if (typeof window !== UNDEF_TYPE) {
            // browser env
            window.UAParser = UAParser;
        }
    }
```

Nevertheless, why can I import UAParser by `import { UAParser } from 'ua-parser-js'`? This code was shown in the following SO answer and GitHub issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171046

https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/issues/423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways how this might work:

- Your toolchain does transpile the `import { UAParser } from 'ua-parser-js'` statement into the legacy `const { UAParser } = require('ua-parser-js');`, which is then executed by node
- Node ESM do support [importing CommonJS modules for compatibility](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs). The `module.exports = UAParser;` will be available as the default import, the `exports.UAParser = UAParser;` will be available the a named import you're doing.